Can audio be played from an isolate in Flutter? Best practices for precise audio?
I'm working on a project which is essentially an audio sequencer. It has an audio event loop which needs to play audio at precise times. The loop runs in an isolate, which seems to be best for the UI. There are 2 problems.
First, I can't get audio to actually play from the isolate. I've tried just_audio and audioplayers, and although the error messages are different with each package, I believe the problem might be this limitation: Limited plugin messages from host platform to Flutter
Second, I can get audio playing by having the audio isolate send messages to play audio in the main isolate. But the send-receive elapsed time of those messages can fluctuate greatly, on the order of 10ms, which is way too much for this.
So, I'm looking for advice on possible solutions: playing audio from an isolate, prioritizing messages from an isolate, best practices for Flutter timing and/or precise audio playback. Would really appreciate any help! Thanks!

on latest google i/o flutter has launched a package flutter_soloud, its for games, and "immersive app" and i assume your kind of app is included on their spec. you can read here

@SayyidJ Thanks!! Looks promising. flutter_soloud actually runs in its own isolate, so while not ideal, which would be in the same isolate as the audio loop (I think), it can receive messages from that isolate. This should at least be an improvement with less competition with UI, etc.
